# MYSQL compare array against db table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have have a multi-select feature which allows the user to tag a company with services. And in my database I have a table with just id and names of those services. What I am trying to do is create a statement that searches to see if the tag already exists, if it does not exist, create it. Could someone help me with the logic of setting this up?

I am just not sure how to go about searching through a table column with an array.

Thanks

```
$company_type = implode(',', $company_type);
 $lookup_tags = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE company_type_id = ?";
  $q_lookup_tags = $conn->prepare($lookup_tags);
   $q_lookup_tags -> execute(array($company_type));
```

How do I perform the select and sort the results into existing and non existing ids?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $query = "";
 $i = 0;
 foreach($company_type as $key=>$type){
    $query.="SELECT $type as type, count(*) as total,* FROM table WHERE company_type_id = ".intval($type);
    if($i < count($company_type)){
        $query.=" UNION ";
    } 
    $i++;
}

$q_lookup_tags = $conn->prepare($query);
$q_lookup_tags -> execute();
```

Comment: just about the second part of the question how would I go about sorting the existing and non existing tags? Usually I perform a row count after a select statement to see if it exists but I have never tried to pass an array through before

Comment: you could use mysql union statement and craft a query. I'll edit my post, give me a sec.

Answer (score 1):

mysql `in` operator is your friend here:

```
$lookup_tags = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE company_type_id in ($company_type)";
```

but if you're using pdo prepared statements you'll need to filter manually

**Edit**

```
$placeHolders=implode(',',array_fill(0,count($company_type),'?'));
$lookup_tags = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE company_type_id in ($placeHolders)";
$qry= $conn->prepare($lookup_tags);
$qry->execute(array_values($company_type));
```

Comment: which I did point out in the original answer. Edited with a safer version